# How to make function in function like a.b.c()

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to make subfunction like `a.b.c()`, I can't find name for this. Sorry for english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is just a function within an object, within another object, like so:

```
const a = {
  b: {
    c: () => "hello World",
  },
};
```

Comment: thanks, i couldn't figure it out =)